# Adding a class while dynamically on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a slider, it moves to the right when going to the next image. It also has a function where in it can move to specific image I used a `ul li` html for this

```
$('#right, #left').on('click', function () {
    slide($(this).attr('id'), 600);
    $('ul#slide-menu').find('li.active').removeClass( 'active' );
    $('ul#slide-menu').addClass( 'active' );
});
```

when the user click the `li`, it will have a class called "active" the color of `li` will change indicating that it is the current image chosen. The problem is that when the slider is automatically moving the function for indicating which image is not working.

This is how my slider moves

```
setInterval(function() {
    slide("right", 600);
}, 5000);
```

I tried to make it this way, but it only removed the class "active" but it is not adding. Any idea on this"?

```
setInterval(function() {
    slide("right", 600);
    $('ul#slide-menu').find('li.active').removeClass( 'active' );
    $('ul#slide-menu').addClass( 'active' );
}, 5000);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTncb/). There is a `ul li` at the bottom, I'm trying to make it also move indicating which image is being displayed.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/NTncb/
There is a ul li at the bottom, I'm trying to make it also move indicating which image is being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding active class to your ul#slide-menu. Not to the child li element... You can achieve this like;

```
$('ul#slide-menu').find('li:visible:first').addClass('active');
```

Edit:

```
var $slider = $('ul#slide-menu');
var $current = $slider.find('li.active');
var $next = $current.next();

if(!$next.length) {
    $next = $slider.find('li:first');
}

$current.removeClass('active');
$next.addClass('active');
```

JS Fiddle with new code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb9xg/

```
function slider() {
    var $slider = $('ul#slide-menu');
    var $current = $slider.find('li.active');

    if(!$current.length) {
        var $next = $slider.find('li:first');
    } else {
        var $next = $current.next();
        $current.removeClass('active');
    }

    if(!$next.length) {
        $next = $slider.find('li:first');
    }

    $next.addClass('active'); 
}

$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){slider();}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: so it would become ,. 
    $('ul#slide-menu').find('li.active').removeClass( 'active' );
    $('ul#slide-menu').find('li:visible:first').addClass('active');
Am I right?

Comment: I have edited my code because i could not see any hide or fadeOut or slideUp method to hide your inactive div and the show next div. The code i'v added to my answer is more accurate to your script now. I will make a fiddle if you can wait.